# I want to learn math do I need to memorise the times tables?

Tags: mental-arithmetic

As a front end developer, I do not need Math, however, I want to seriously learn it so that, maybe, one day, I might be able to get so good at it as to get into AI.

I started with Algebra 1 and quickly realized I needed to brush up on pre-algebra. I found a course on great courses and going through it.

As I write this I learned and practiced long divisions and fractions.

At the moment, if I need to work out `3x9` I might need to do `9+9+9`.

I'm thinking the more I work with math, the more clear the pattern will become, for example, the 9 times tables are the number minus one and then whatever goes up to 10 `9xY = [Y-1][10-Y]`

Should I stop and memorize the times tables - which I find the most boring thing in the world. Or should I carry on and trust that it will become natural?

Comment: You may find the pattern recognition a more useful skill than memorising the actual numbers: for example spotting that multiplication by $5$ is the same as multiplying by $10$ and then dividing by $2$

Comment: If that's an issue for you, how will you commit to memory the many important theorems about objects which have many different properties,  and how they relate to each other?

Comment: Or doing $3\times 10 - 3$ instead of $9+9+9$ (adding to @Henry comment).

Comment: There is a strong distinction between mathematics which is a huge collection of diverse things and arithmetic which is the kind of calculations you are mentioning. You don't have to be good at arithmetic to be good at maths. You don't need to memorise times tables, it would be better to work out how to multiply any two numbers together using tricks such as this: http://www.savory.de/maths23.htm Then eventually you will see the patterns in your head and be able to progress.

Comment: @BenedictW.J.Irwin I'm new, I've read, heard and seen people say the same thing. I want to get there eventually (to the maths), am I right, I can't get to the math without going through arithmetic?

Comment: @DavidPeterson I don't see the correlation. The problem is not that I have an issue with it, after all with use of flash cards I could learn them. It's just a case of finding it boring. As for learning other theorems, they would be the logical progression. **I'm not saying memorising the TT is difficult it just needs its own time, should I spend my time memorising it or move forward?**

Comment: Perhaps you can do both at the same time.  I was in grade school when learning the times table was considered just part of education.  It was never a major block of instruction.  Not remembering a particular product was never a problem.  You will most likely develop your own shortcuts for quick answers so that you are not distracted from what you may be studying.

Comment: Possibly relevant (and don't skip the comments): [What are the arguments for and against learning multiplication table by heart?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/352/745) *AND* [Why are times tables thought to be important?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/10189/745) *AND* [When should a kid have memorized the multiplication table?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/9667/745) *AND* [How many hours / school years does it take for the average child to memorize the $10\times 10$ addition and multiplication tables?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/16684/745)